# How can i remove the duplicate element from a xml document without scribbling the structure of xml using c#

Tags: c#, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

Below is the sample xml .

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Terms>  
   <Term Id="D7923D9888BF100482C2CB8225D5863E" Name="Television" IsPlaceholder="false" />  
   <Term Id="F25AF2D07E4E100484F5DF092526B43E" Name="General news" IsPlaceholder="false">
     <ChildTerms>
       <Term Id="04969DF089DA10048141D56C852D093E" Name="Bombings" IsPlaceholder="false" />
       <Term Id="0E8CF338896510048024D56C852D093E" Name="Protests and demonstrations" IsPlaceholder="false" />
       <Term Id="17956128897810048CE8D56C852D093E" Name="Law and order" IsPlaceholder="false">
     <ChildTerms>
       <Term Id="3EC37E763F534FDB8A10C63768DAD1B7" Name="Executions" IsPlaceholder="false" />
       <Term Id="78C99FE8829F100481B5DF092526B43E" Name="Trials" IsPlaceholder="false" />
       <Term Id="C72CC1E0883210048566AE2AC3A6923E" Name="Prison breaks" IsPlaceholder="false" />
       <Term Id="CD42D51088321004856EAE2AC3A6923E" Name="Prison riots" IsPlaceholder="false" />
    </ChildTerms>
   </Term>
   <Term Id="31711EC0894B10048983BA0A2B2CA13E" Name="Accidents and disasters" IsPlaceholder="false">
    <ChildTerms>
      <Term Id="2D777E23418C4A61AB869F88F0CC22B5" Name="Industrial accidents" IsPlaceholder="false">
        <ChildTerms>
          <Term Id="6EF1C84088321004850DAE2AC3A6923E" Name="Mining accidents" IsPlaceholder="false" />
          <Term Id="77A15F9213344CF8AEFBD6560C618C9A" Name="Oil spills" IsPlaceholder="false" />
        </ChildTerms>
      </Term>
      <Term Id="439E22A0894B100489C4BA0A2B2CA13E" Name="Structural failures" IsPlaceholder="false">
        <ChildTerms>
          <Term Id="513CDC30894B10048A8E87A309043C03" Name="Bridge collapses" IsPlaceholder="false" />
          <Term Id="513D0340894B10048A8E87A309043C03" Name="Building collapses" IsPlaceholder="false" />
        </ChildTerms>
      </Term>
      <Term Id="58AD538091C7100480A9A55C96277D3E" Name="Evacuations" IsPlaceholder="false" />
      <Term Id="6B5B04B0882F100480E6AE2AC3A6923E" Name="Fires" IsPlaceholder="false">
        <ChildTerms>
          <Term Id="69D001C8896410048EBBD56C852D093E" Name="Residential fires" IsPlaceholder="false" />
          <Term Id="6C61CA38882F10048FA88BB2970C7204" Name="Wildfires" IsPlaceholder="false" />
        </ChildTerms>
      </Term>
      <Term Id="6C633968882F10048FA88BB2970C7204" Name="Floods" IsPlaceholder="false" />
      <Term Id="7448DD4882A0100481DDDF092526B43E" Name="Natural disasters" IsPlaceholder="false">
        <ChildTerms>
          <Term Id="6C61CA38882F10048FA88BB2970C7204" Name="Wildfires" IsPlaceholder="false" />
          <Term Id="6C615120882F10048FA68BB2970C7204" Name="Earthquakes" IsPlaceholder="false" />
          <Term Id="6C618FA0882F10048FA78BB2970C7204" Name="Tsunamis" IsPlaceholder="false" />
          <Term Id="6C6281D0882F10048FA88BB2970C7204" Name="Droughts" IsPlaceholder="false" />
          <Term Id="6C62C050882F10048FA88BB2970C7204" Name="Landslides and mudslides" IsPlaceholder="false" />
          <Term Id="6C633968882F10048FA98BB2970C7204" Name="Avalanches" IsPlaceholder="false" />
          <Term Id="A6F2C1C887E110048A6E8BEAE5FD5C07" Name="Tornados" IsPlaceholder="false" />
          <Term Id="B4600998883010048C189528EB155503" Name="Volcanic eruptions" IsPlaceholder="false" />
          <Term Id="DC90FFA0686948409257760CC35E98EB" Name="Tropical cyclones" IsPlaceholder="false">
            <ChildTerms>
              **<Term Id="6C6377E8882F10048FAB8BB2970C7204" Name="Hurricanes" IsPlaceholder="false" />**
              <Term Id="A6F2C1C887E110048A6D8BEAE5FD5C07" Name="Tropical storms" IsPlaceholder="false" />
            </ChildTerms>
          </Term>
        </ChildTerms>
      </Term>
      <Term Id="B6503CF08830100482EFAE2AC3A6923E" Name="Power outages" IsPlaceholder="false" />
      <Term Id="CCC363A0882F10048140AE2AC3A6923E" Name="Explosions" IsPlaceholder="false" />
      <Term Id="E20E7174E0154782B8733D180A799D34" Name="Transportation accidents" IsPlaceholder="false">
        <ChildTerms>
          <Term Id="3C105048882F100489FD9528EB155503" Name="Automotive accidents" IsPlaceholder="false" />
          <Term Id="3C107758882F100489FE9528EB155503" Name="Maritime accidents" IsPlaceholder="false" />
          <Term Id="41687660882F10048A199528EB155503" Name="Plane crashes" IsPlaceholder="false" />
          <Term Id="6AA161B575F64C62993BC3E9CD82BB69" Name="Rail accidents" IsPlaceholder="false" />
        </ChildTerms>
      </Term>
    </ChildTerms>
  </Term>
  <Term Id="48612B807C2B4B93BBBACBF54F547AD5" Name="Crime" IsPlaceholder="false">
    <ChildTerms>
      <Term Id="13C6A480899B10048B9DD56C852D093E" Name="Violent crime" IsPlaceholder="false">
        <ChildTerms>
          <Term Id="5018B8F4DED948128561C5AF2144CA66" Name="Shootings" IsPlaceholder="false">
            <ChildTerms>
              <Term Id="312A72707E8510048A118087FC32D30C" Name="School shootings" IsPlaceholder="false" />
            </ChildTerms>
          </Term>
          <Term Id="92DD72A8899B10048F2CD56C852D093E" Name="Assassinations" IsPlaceholder="false" />
          <Term Id="C5A59C298A2A4A36A618EFB20DF09A3C" Name="Homicide" IsPlaceholder="false" />
          <Term Id="FCAF54924FA3415DA977901DDB1E2EA7" Name="Gang-related crime" IsPlaceholder="false" />
        </ChildTerms>
      </Term>
      <Term Id="CA356A4172C64D3FA631803BA6CCC074" Name="Arson" IsPlaceholder="false" />
      <Term Id="CD80007770234E6AA95991F7D3B0C737" Name="Hate crimes" IsPlaceholder="false" />
    </ChildTerms>
  </Term>
  <Term Id="5F7806EEC29A4884B038A26D799E9326" Name="Strikes" IsPlaceholder="false" />
  <Term Id="5FC806A87DF7100483EBDF092526B43E" Name="Weather" IsPlaceholder="false">
    <ChildTerms>
      <Term Id="A6F2C1C887E110048A6E8BEAE5FD5C07" Name="Tornados" IsPlaceholder="false" />
      <Term Id="88C2A7E08886100487FECB8225D5863E" Name="Storms" IsPlaceholder="false">
        <ChildTerms>
          <Term Id="DC90FFA0686948409257760CC35E98EB" Name="Tropical cyclones" IsPlaceholder="false">
            <ChildTerms>
              **<Term Id="6C6377E8882F10048FAB8BB2970C7204" Name="Hurricanes" IsPlaceholder="false" />**
              <Term Id="A6F2C1C887E110048A6D8BEAE5FD5C07" Name="Tropical storms" IsPlaceholder="false" />
            </ChildTerms>
          </Term>
          <Term Id="59143B3791444BF7BD11992B42B8EA2E" Name="Wind storms" IsPlaceholder="false" />
          <Term Id="A6F248B087E110048A6B8BEAE5FD5C07" Name="Blizzards" IsPlaceholder="false" />
          <Term Id="A6F2873087E110048A6C8BEAE5FD5C07" Name="Thunderstorms" IsPlaceholder="false" />
          <Term Id="A6F3004887E110048A6F8BEAE5FD5C07" Name="Ice storms" IsPlaceholder="false" />
        </ChildTerms>
      </Term>
    </ChildTerms>
  </Term>
  <Term Id="7CF243908830100481E9AE2AC3A6923E" Name="War and unrest" IsPlaceholder="false">
    <ChildTerms>
      <Term Id="3510D930896410048E5CD56C852D093E" Name="Genocides" IsPlaceholder="false" />
      <Term Id="535DB1708832100484DBAE2AC3A6923E" Name="Troop withdrawals" IsPlaceholder="false" />
      <Term Id="5FEF4190897910048240D56C852D093E" Name="Massacres" IsPlaceholder="false" />
      <Term Id="6BCC38A43C5C4BC196FB108112EAA6C1" Name="Civil wars" IsPlaceholder="false" />
      <Term Id="98C3B8C5D6AF41C296A3CA1E4C0977ED" Name="Terrorism" IsPlaceholder="false">
        <ChildTerms>
          <Term Id="D7F9E33889701004837FD56C852D093E" Name="Terrorist attacks" IsPlaceholder="false" />
        </ChildTerms>
      </Term>
      <Term Id="9BEC03A0883310048673AE2AC3A6923E" Name="Military occupations" IsPlaceholder="false" />
      <Term Id="B9779BC8896410048F4CD56C852D093E" Name="Troop deployments" IsPlaceholder="false" />
    </ChildTerms>
  </Term>
  <Term Id="877CB3C0899A10048ABBD56C852D093E" Name="Transportation" IsPlaceholder="false">
    <ChildTerms>
      <Term Id="E20E7174E0154782B8733D180A799D34" Name="Transportation accidents" IsPlaceholder="false">
        <ChildTerms>
          <Term Id="3C105048882F100489FD9528EB155503" Name="Automotive accidents" IsPlaceholder="false" />
          <Term Id="3C107758882F100489FE9528EB155503" Name="Maritime accidents" IsPlaceholder="false" />
          <Term Id="41687660882F10048A199528EB155503" Name="Plane crashes" IsPlaceholder="false" />
          <Term Id="6AA161B575F64C62993BC3E9CD82BB69" Name="Rail accidents" IsPlaceholder="false" />
        </ChildTerms>
      </Term>
      <Term Id="9031A908899A10048BAFCECE19677003" Name="Traffic" IsPlaceholder="false" />
      <Term Id="90321E38899A10048BAFCECE19677003" Name="Air travel disruptions" IsPlaceholder="false" />
      <Term Id="90321E38899A10048BB0CECE19677003" Name="Rail travel disruptions" IsPlaceholder="false" />
    </ChildTerms>
  </Term>
  <Term Id="9D48E670883110048405AE2AC3A6923E" Name="International incidents" IsPlaceholder="false" />
  <Term Id="A0433408883010048BE79528EB155503" Name="Riots" IsPlaceholder="false" />
  <Term Id="CAEFF3958DE64F4D989F5EF1209BD073" Name="Humanitarian crises" IsPlaceholder="false">
    <ChildTerms>
      <Term Id="463C2098896410048E93D56C852D093E" Name="Famine" IsPlaceholder="false" />
    </ChildTerms>
  </Term>
  <Term Id="CE211E3891B0100483C1A55C96277D3E" Name="Record setting events" IsPlaceholder="false" />
  <Term Id="DA6509F88971100486C5D56C852D093E" Name="Search and rescue efforts" IsPlaceholder="false" />
</ChildTerms>
```

as you can see there are two entries for **Hurricanes**(Please find for ** mark before an elment) i just want to remove any one of them .I tried using Linq but it is scribbling the structure of the xml. Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**LINQ Solution to remove all Duplicates and Keep one**

```
XElement xml = XElement.Load("data.xml");

string toRemove ="Hurricanes";

//Find the Number of Duplicates
int duplicateCount=xml.Descendants("Term")
                      .GroupBy(xe => xe.Attribute("Name").Value)
                      .Where(x => x.Key == toRemove)
                      .Select<IGrouping<string, XElement>, int>(y => y.Count())
                      .First();

//Remove all duplicates but one
xml.Descendants("Term").Where(xe => xe.Attribute("Name").Value == toRemove)
                       .Take(duplicateCount-1)
                       .Remove();

xml.Save("moddata.xml");
```

Comment: That removes the 1st element, which works if you have only 2 hurricanes. If you have more, you need to remove all except the first, or you could use the code above and put a while loop around counting the occurrences and proceed removing if there is more than 1 hurricane element.

Comment: But i can't hard code a attribute's value.It might possible tomorrow i will have to remove another duplicity for a different element.For ex:- it might happen with "Tornados".

Comment: you can easily replace it with a string variable if u want it.i hardcoded so its easy for you to understand

Comment: yes i just took all the Duplicate nodes in a List and by looping through that list i removed all the duplicates.

Thanks a ton Codelgnoto.

Comment: That's a nice solution now: +1 !

Answer (score 1):

I might try XPath instead.  You can use XDocument's XPathSelectElements method to get a list of elements that have a Name attribute with the value of "Hurricanes":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Throw that IEnumerable list of elements into an IList by using ToList and then call Remove on each node:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.remove.aspx

That should remove all of the elements from wherever they exist in the XML tree.

Comment: I really can not hard code to find the particular element and remove that because in future the xml might change and may be it is possible instead of Hurricane,there will be duplicate elements for Name "Tornados".